# Automatic resize of jsf inputtext

Tags: css, jsf, richfaces

I have a Problem with `<h:inputText>`. It is used within a table for Input and Display of values - the Problem is - it doesn't resize according to the value and cuts of the Content.

```
<rich:dataTable id="featuresList" value="#{model.rowProjectionSet}"
        var="row" rowKeyVar="rowIndex">
        <f:param name="rowIndex" value="#{rowIndex}" />
    <rich:column id="rowName" colspan="1" style="background-color: #ECF4FE;height: 25px; width:30px;">          
        <f:facet name="header">
            &nbsp;
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{row.name}"/>
    </rich:column>

    <util:columns forEachItems="#{model.columnsProjectionSet}" varName="column" 
            style="text-align:center; height: 25px; min-width:50px;" headerClass="itemColumnHeader" >           
        <f:facet name="header">
          <h:outputText value="#{column.name}"/>
        </f:facet>
        <f:facet name="tableGuiId"> 
          <h:outputText value="combination_#{column.name}" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:inputText value="#{model.getCombinationEntry(row,column).value}" disabled="#{model.readonly}"  
                styleClass="#{syntacticCategoryGUIUtil.getStateStyle(model.getCombinationEntry(row,column))}"                    
                style="border:none; height: 25px; overflow: visible;" />
    </util:columns>
</rich:dataTable>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You can take the [tour] first and learn [ask] a good question and create a [mcve].  That makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: JSF is in this regard a nothing more than an html generator. Client-side the `h:inputText` is a plain html input field which does not resize either. Look how to solve that and port it to jsf then!!!